# GeocodeService.Search returns ZERO_RESULTS From some values

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map, lightning-map

Lightning map works good for most of records we used, but for some returns zero results.
We have a
for describing purpose i cut out `&callback=XXX&key=YYY&token=ZZZ` from each link below

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sAustralia%20Australia%20Australia&7sUS&9sen-US`
Returns proper resoult for country

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sQueensland%20Queensland%20Queensland&7sUS&9sen-US` Returns proper resoult for State Queenland

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sVictoria%20Victoria%20Victoria&7sUS&9sen-US`
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sVictoria%20Victoria%20Victoria&7sAU&9sen-AU`
Both with default and Australia region code returns
Error: Geocoding Victoria Victoria Victoria failed. Google geocoder status is ZERO_RESULTS

Another issue is with
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sPortland&7sAU&9sen-AU`
Even when using Australian  locales on SF user for REGION https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/specification
Param to be set Australia it pinpoints Portland in US
https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage